# Erro no recebimento de header no servidor PHP enviado via requisição http

Tags: php, http

Galerá estou precisando da ajuda de vocês.

Minha aplicação cliente restfull está enviando um header chamado 'Auth' com um token de autenticação para o servidor PHP. Quando faço os testes com um servidor rodando em localhost funciona tudo beleza. Entretanto, quando coloco o mesmo código no servidor da Localweb não funciona, não consigo recuperar o header, o código abaixo cai sempre no else como se eu não estivesse enviando o header.

```
 function authenticateApp() {
    $headers =   apache_request_headers();

    if (isset($headers["Authorization"])) {
     //Se o header foi existe faz os teste de autenticação;
    } else {

        //Se não foi passado retorna um código de erro
       //No localhost funciona, no servidor da Localweb sempre cai aqui.   


    }
}
```

Obs: que tanto no localhost quanto na localweb estou usando a versão 5.6 do PHP. Minha máquina local é Windows e o servidor é Linux, será que tem algo a ver?

Comment: de um print_r na váriavel $headers e poste o retorno aqui.

Comment: Valeu pelo comentário Hiago Souza, graças a ele consegui resolver.

Comment: é isso ai :) (Y)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problema resolvido. Ao dar um print_r na variável e fazer mais alguns testes percebi que o problema só ocorria quando eu nomeava o header como "Authorization" ele não aparecia na lista de headers, alterei o nome e não tive mais problema.

```
function authenticateApp() {
$headers =   apache_request_headers();

if (isset($headers["novo_nome"])) {
 //Bastou renomear o header
} else {

    //Se não foi passado retorna um código de erro

}
```

}